# Converting a pdf to jpg images using in Qt

Tags: c++, pdf, jpeg, image-conversion

the heading says it all actually:

i want to convert a pdf file into several jpg images. This is to be a part of a software coded in c++ (I'm using Qt for my interface if that matters... :)

Preferably i want the images output to be 72 dpi.

Is there a easy way to do this?

Please comment if you need any more information form me, I'm grateful for any help, tips or answer!

Comment: Please change the text in your question so it doesn't come up in google.  It's a small thing but the answer you accepted is not really c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take [pdf2image](http://code.google.com/p/pdf2image/) utility, and run it from you program, collecting its output files.

If you really need single executable (why?) — take a look at its source, and rip everything from it.

Comment: This sounds like a solution, I'll try it when i get back later today. I need the software to be a completely automatic solution. It is supposed to grind through PDFs unmonitored and upload results to a local database. Thank you :)

Comment: Why exactly do you need C++?  That seems to me a perfect case for Perl, Ruby or Python.

Comment: This project is using OpenCV which is written in C/C++. Can i combine these languages somehow? I have some experience with Ruby but not much.

Comment: none of the solutions seems to be simple to implement. How would you solve this problem? how would you call an second executable for this? sqadette?

Comment: Sorry but have you read my answer?XPDF and poppler  is what pdf2image is based on. You even have example C++ code in the link I provided for doing this kind of stuff without having to call an external program.If you want implementation details feel free to ask as I have already done this kind of stuff numerous times with XPDF in my C/C++ programs

Comment: Hi, right you are! I'm sorry, please see me comment below your answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use poppler (or xpdf). You'll have full control of the rendering resolution and can take advantage of image output devices (ImageOutputDev) which will render pages to a framebuffer.Saving this framebuffer to jpeg with libjpeg is ,then , pretty straightforward.

Comment: In fact Poppler even has been the subject of a QT Quarterly column see "Poppler: Displaying PDF Files with Qt" http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq27-poppler.html

Comment: Hi, sorry i did not quite understand the answer at first. I'm new to C++ and Qt. Can you maybe share a code example of how you have done this before? I know its allot to ask, but i learn from examples and i cant find any examples of this out there.

Comment: Here we go, https://gist.github.com/3952671 .This example assumes you have downloaded XPDF code base and included it in your project. It uses a a SplashOutputDev , makes XPDF renders each page of an input PDF to it and dump the pixels to one jpeg file per page.Ask if you have any questions on the (quite dirty) code

Comment: BTW you'll have to link to libjpeg and to freetype. You may also need to  add the line "#define HAVE_FREETYPE_FREETYPE_H 1" in xpdf/aconf.h  to make sure SplashOutputDev rely on freetype to render text

Comment: Thank you! :) I need to learn some more C++ i think, but this helps allot!